# Developing filters on a list of jobs in an android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android mobile application. Application lists all the available jobs. I need to implement filters on jobs so that refined list appears. I have filters like "By Location", " By salary", " By date", "By Skills". What is the approach for developing filters? Which UI widgets are more suitable for that?

Comment: all you need is an Adapter and AdapterView that displays Adapter's data

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are just asking for an Android Widget. Hope you know how to requery for the data. Try using [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).